# I need to find the second largest and smallest number in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

`below is my array`

```
<pre>
   let input = [29, 75, 115, 12, 89, 29, 103, 65, 100, 78, 115, 102, 55, 214];
</pre>
```

now i need the second largest from it.

Comment: sort, then shift and pop

Comment: or ... `let [smallest] = input.sort((a, b) => a - b);` and `let [_, secondLargest] = input.sort((a, b) => b - a);`